# getting all long and lat from pandas dataframe via geopy

Tags: python, pandas, loops, geopy

I have a data frame with location data like "Los Angeles, CA".

The goal is the iterate over all entries of the column and save the long and lat in a new column. Any input or tips are highly welcome !

I tried it for a single value and it worked.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="xxx")
location=geolocator.geocode(df['Location'][1])
print(location.longitude)
print(location.latitude)
```

-117.8704931

33.7500378

Now, As a beginner I thought let's do a for loop:

```
df['lat']=0
print(df['Location'][1])
for x in range(1,len(df)+1):
    location = geolocator.geocode(df['Location'][x])
    df['loc'][x]=location.latitude
```

I get the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df['loc'][x]=location.latitude
```

and after ~2 mins the following error:

```
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\skpok\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 344, in _call_geocoder
    page = requester(req, timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\skpok\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\skpok\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\skpok\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\skpok\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\skpok\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\skpok\Downloads\test123.py", line 12, in <module>
    location = geolocator.geocode(df['Location'][x])
  File "C:\Users\skpok\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\osm.py", line 309, in geocode
    self._call_geocoder(url, timeout=timeout), exactly_one
  File "C:\Users\skpok\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 367, in _call_geocoder
    raise GeocoderTimedOut('Service timed out')
geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out
```

Comment: With regards to service timeouts you might find the geopy's RateLimiter class helpful: https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.18.1/#usage-with-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominatim has a maximum request per second rule (1 per second).  You should try to put in a clause where the script sleeps between loops.

You can try

```
import time
df['lat']=0
print(df['Location'][1])
for x in range(1,len(df)+1):
    location = geolocator.geocode(df['Location'][x])
    time.sleep(2)
    df.at[x, 'lat']=location.latitude
```

Comment: Thanks so much, given that I have 100k entries, this will take quite a bit of time. Maybe I should look into renting a cheap server to do it , instead of letting my machine run for that many hours

Comment: I've used Google Maps for something like this. They allow around 300K at the start for free using their API. And if you're using geopy, you just have to change a line and a half of code.